# Restarting activemq route in camel when receiving a "Connection.start()" message

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have a an activemq camel route that stops receiving messages at some point and requires a restart.  I am not sure how to programmatically detect and fix this situation.

My route looks like so:

`from("activemq:queue:Consumer.app.VirtualTopic.msg?messageConverter=#convertMsg")`

It's all configured in Spring like so:

```
<!-- Configure the Message Bus Factory -->
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="com.local.messaging.activemq.SpringSslContextConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="${jms.broker.url}" />
  <property name="sslContext" ref="sslContext" />
</bean>

<!-- Connect the Message Bus Factory to Camel.  The 'activemq' bean
     name is necessary for Camel to pick it up automatically -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" depends-on="jmsFactory">
  <property name="usePooledConnection" value="true" />
  <property name="connectionFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
      <property name="maxConnections" value="20" />
      <property name="maximumActive" value="10" />
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Finally, the broker URL is configured like so:

`jms.broker.url=failover://(ssl://amq1:61616,ssl://amq1:61616)`

This starts up just fine and works like a champ most of the time.  Every so often, though, I see this message in the logs:

`Received a message on a connection which is not yet started. Have you forgotten to call Connection.start()? Connection: ActiveMQConnection {<details>}`

I suspect strongly that this happens after the message bus has restarted, but as I have no direct access to the message bus, I don't know that for certain.  I don't know that that matters.

The keys for me are:

1. How do I programmatically detect this situation?  There doesn't appear to be any exception thrown or the like and the only way I've seen this is by parsing through log files.
2. After detecting it, how do I fix it?  Do I need to `start()` and `stop()` the route or is there a cleaner way?

Finally, I did see some suggestions that this case should be handled by activemq, using the `failover` scheme.  As shown above, I am using `failover` and this still happens.

Comment: what version of Camel/AMQ are you using?

Comment: org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.9.2, org.apache.activemq.activemq-camel:5.4.2